# jQuery array .map inside .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary, each

I have an array inside an `$.each` function. I want to iterate through it to create a new or modified array. But I need to access the `$(this)` from the outside `$.each` loop:

```
// target these data attributes:
$selector = $('[data-my0], [data-my1], [data-my2]');

$.each($selector, function() {        

    var $this = $(this), // cache selector
        keys = ['my0', 'my1', 'my2']; // array of data keys

    // I want to use the keys array to make a vals array to this:
    // var vals = [$this.data('my0'), $this.data('my1'), $this.data('my2')];

    // This doesn't seem to work (can't read from length 0 error):
    var vals = $.map( keys, function( key ) { return $this.data(key); });

});
```

I think it's possible to do this using using `$.each` or `$.map` but this is where I'm stuck. I know `$(this)` not used normally with `$.map` like it is with `$.each`. In this case, I'm trying to pass the `$this` from the outside that represents the selector.

Comment: Not part of the problem, but you can write `$selector.each(...)` too.

Comment: You have a type with `);` I think.

Comment: @pimvdb yes that was a problem too but it wouldn't cause that "can't read from length 0" error. I don't get that error in [the jsfiddle I did](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/XcvUS/1/) from the code.

Comment: @pimvdb Thanks (that's what happens when I have to wake up at 5:30 and drive my mom to the airport LOL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait - you're passing "vals" into your "$.map()" cal instead of "keys":

```
var vals = $.map( keys, function( key ) { return $this.data(key); });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/XcvUS/1/) is a jsfiddle.  The code works just fine, though without seeing your actual HTML it's hard to know exactly what you expect to happen.

Comment: That's good and bad b/c it means this works but I must have a problem elsewhere. Thank you :)

Comment: and the html is like `<div data-my0='hello' data-my1='out' data-my2='there'></div>` - worked that way too in the fiddle. Thx again.